# Hardware Suggestion: SIM Card Gateway - Receive Shortcodes

Tags: automation

Im looking for a solution to where I can utilize a gateway to manage 64+ SIM cards to receive US SMS Shortcodes.

I’ve not found equipment that specifically states it has this feature. And I’ve seen gateways and then an additional piece of equipment with antennas and I’m not sure if both are needed.

Thank you for your time.